# Which is the best way to calculate Year/Month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to group data by year/month. Data is stored in a column with datatype `date`. There are several ways to cut off the day information and leave year-month.

I felt using built-in `year` and `month` functions should perform better than string operations. I played around a bit an was wondering whether this could be true: In terms of perfomance I could not find any difference between a calculation of `YYYYMM` by using `year` and `month` functions and the string operation `left(.., 7)` returning a value of `YYYY-MM`.

I cannot see any difference in the execution plan's numbers, not even in far more complex situations than shown here.

```
declare @t1 table (mydate date)

insert @t1 select '2017-01-30'   
   select year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate)
   from @t1

   select left(mydate, 7)
   from @t1
```

Same plan, same I/O, same CPU, same ...

Can this be true?

Or simply: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "best" is open to interpretation. I think you mean most performant.

Comment: SELECT list scalar expressions  have very low impact on execution plan provided they have the same columns as arguments.

Comment: Not sure how your testing was performed, nor the scale of the data tested against, but it is a "truism" that numeric operations are faster than string operations. Numerics can also mean lower memory needs and/or storage. So if confronted with roughly equal evidence, go for the numeric option.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: My 'problem' is that they all perfom the same. As what conserns "best": left(...,7) is shortest = best performance in writing but is not very robust as it also will return something if mydate is a string (e.g. '30.01.2017'). datepart-functions might be best to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to talk about performance, let's take a look at performance.

```
set statistics io on;
set statistics time on;
```

My [datelist] test table had ~92 million rows.

Using your queries 1-4 from your updated info, here are the IO & Time results.

Since it's a one column table, the IO was uniform. All four queries returned this:

```
(208 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-
ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead 
reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-
ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead 
reads 0.
Table 'datelist'. Scan count 9, logical reads 136071, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-
ahead reads 0.
```

You'll see, though, that options 1 and 4 are the most performant from a time perspective, using native date manipulations, and option 3, using a combination of date and string functions, was far and away the least efficient.

The YEAR and MONTH functions carry the day.

```
q1

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 61064 ms,  elapsed time = 7699 ms.

q2

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 89064 ms,  elapsed time = 11191 ms.

q3

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 103875 ms,  elapsed time = 13113 ms.

q4

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 68125 ms,  elapsed time = 8558 ms.
```

Comment: I can reproduce the results with little difference: #4 performes best in a 250 Mio table on a datetime column but with only very small advance over #1. So the best to read way #4 is the best perfoming! #2 and #3 are three times slower on datatime columns and #3 would give faulty results here.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a really important point about SQL:  Databases are designed to manage and handle data.  Perhaps because the reading, writing, and caching of data is hidden behind `select` and `from`, users of the language don't necessarily think much about these operations.

And yet.  Moving data from disk to memory dominates most queries.

You are comparing pretty minor operations on a single field.  These operations are negligible compared to the overhead of reading and writing the data to get the data in memory.

The moral is to focus on making the code readable and maintainable, and not on micro-optimizations.

Note:  Some functions can have high overhead, even relative to the movement of data.  This is especially true for operations on large strings, object, XML, and the like.

Comment: What do you think is the most readable and maintainable way to calculate YYYYMM in SQL Server?

Comment: @Christian4143 . . . `format(getdate(), 'yyyymm')`.

Comment: It seems that this syntax is even not very readable: Your format-statement extracts the minutes! (Sould be 'yyyyMM')

Comment: The format-Syntax might be nice to read and understand, but it is by far the most CPU-consuming: more than 100-times more CPU compared to year() and month()-Syntax. This is really slow and far away from 'micro-optimizations'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you need on your result, there are few approaches:

- use EOMONTH() function and round your date field to the last day of the month and group by it like that `EOMONTH(your_date_column);`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql
- use DATEPART() and group by two columns. `DATEPART(YEAR, your_date_column), DATEPART(MONTH, your_date_column);`

Also - if this is done frequently, perhaps you could simply store year and month columns separately and group by them.

Comment: Another option might be a calendar table.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yep, it could be. Add this as an answer, it's probably better than mine! :)

Comment: @HoneyBadger: A calender table is a very good idea, although it completly disavowes the idea of a database-server.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value of type yyyymm:

```
select cast(datepart(year,mydate) as nvarchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(datepart(month,mydate) as nvarchar(2)),2)
```

Comment: I think this is very hard to read and the result is the same as above. The numbers within the plan are same as well. As if the optimizer would understand what we are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed answer to my own question, but an update on this. I checked with a table with about 40 Mio. rows:

```
create table xxx.dbo.test (mydate date)

insert xxx.dbo.test select [some date field] from [some table]
```

--39.861.927 rows

--462,055 MB

Here are the suggested queries and the resulting plans:

## 1

```
 select count(*), year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate)
 from xxx.dbo.test
 group by year(mydate) * 100 + month(mydate)
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJHPmuDTZ

## 2

```
select  count(*), left(mydate, 7)
from xxx.dbo.test
group by left(mydate, 7)
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJZ67uPT-

## 3

```
select count(*), cast(datepart(year,mydate) as nvarchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(datepart(month,mydate) as nvarchar(2)),2)
from xxx.dbo.test
group by cast(datepart(year,mydate) as nvarchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(datepart(month,mydate) as nvarchar(2)),2)
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry8bVdv6Z

## 4

```
select count(*), DATEPART(YEAR, mydate), DATEPART(MONTH, mydate) 
from xxx.dbo.test
group by DATEPART(YEAR, mydate), DATEPART(MONTH, mydate)
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkQSNuDTW

As you can see they all perform mostly the same (#1 is leading).

So don't worry?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if this year/month part is or will be a major business object you should consider the option of create two new calculated INT columns for year and month. This way you will gain much in the future where sql will calculate *1 on insert and *1 on any update on date (if any) instead of calculating at every different select statement it is used, every time it is executed.

Comment: I tried this. A smallint and a tinyint-column does save space and makes some things faster. But you have to care about consistent data. You should enforce constraints ensuring there are really dates stored in the combination of this two fields. This is not easy and makes things more complicated. See Gordon Linoff's answer: This is exacty the point not to forget with databases.

Comment: Perhaps not clear - you add year and month on top of your standard date or datetime column, you dont replace it. A datetime column still works as before plus the (sql calculated fields) year and month are generated as year() and month() of the datetime value. So nothing needs validation or anything. In order to understand performance in that case you should try both approaches with e.g. 15 million records selecting information and use filtering on THAT columns. Then you will realize that the datetime column index turns unusable when you filter on a run-time converted year-month part.